# How can I resolve `bind_rows()` error?

Tags: database

So I wanted to download massive amounts of COX1 (or COI) sequences from any available database. I found this script in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/13187/16657 this comment that achieves just that using the `bold` R package. I changed the script to fit my data preference:

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rentrez)
library(bold)    # API interface to BOLD
library(taxize)  # for NCBI taxonomy lookup
library(seqinr)  # for FASTA output

set_entrez_key()

# get class-level taxa within "Mollusca" from NCBI taxonomy
taxa <- downstream("Mollusca", db = "ncbi", downto = "order")
# check if taxa present in BOLD
checks <- bold_tax_name(taxa$Mollusca$childtaxa_name)
taxa_bold <- checks[!is.na(checks$taxon),]$taxon

# Download sequences from BOLD for each class-level taxon
sequences <- map(taxa_bold, bold_seq, marker = 'COI-5P') %>%
  flatten() %>%
  bind_rows()

# Convert the list of sequences to a data frame
sequences_df <- do.call(rbind, sequences)


# Write sequences to a file
write.fasta(
  sequences = as.list(sequences_df$sequence), 
  names = as.list(sequences_df$id), 
  nbchar = 80, 
  file.out = 'coi5p.fasta'
)
```

In the aforementioned thread, this script worked but now that I ran it I got the following error:

```
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am not sure what to do for this. I commented on the original thread but since it is kind of old I decided to post about it here.

Note: the `set_entrez_key()` requires a NCBI API key which you can get by registering on NCBI.

Edit #1: The `sequences` object before the `flatten()` command is a large list containing 53 elements. After the command, the object becomes a large list with 257 elements.

Comment: Can you please show the object as it appears before and after the 'flatten' command? It's unusual for me to see that command in R code, and this is just before the `bind_rows` command that you're concerned about, so it will probably be important for working out what's going wrong.

Comment: @gringer I edited the question with the details about the object.

Comment: Please show the head of the object, or the first few lines of output. Your text description is not detailed enough for me to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. After @gringer mentioned that they had not seen the `flatten` command I decided to dig deeper. Turns out the command has been superseded  in purrr 1.0.0. So I will be posting the new script for anyone who seeks an updated version of the one in the old thread.

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rentrez)
library(bold)    # API interface to BOLD
library(taxize)  # for NCBI taxonomy lookup
library(seqinr)  # for FASTA output
library(rBLAST)  


set_entrez_key("d00fee673c4499df4c2479ba5fd71850b308") #my ncbi api key, this is essential for pulling the taxonomy through ncbi

# get class-level taxa within "Mollusca" from NCBI taxonomy
taxa <- downstream("Mollusca", db = "ncbi", downto = "class") #setting the taxonomic level of the search. it will pull sequences for all mollusca but seperately for each class. if the search is large change to a lower taxonomic level

# check if taxa present in BOLD
checks <- bold_tax_name(taxa$Mollusca$childtaxa_name) 
taxa_bold <- checks[!is.na(checks$taxon),]$taxon

# Download sequences from BOLD for each class-level taxon
sequences <- map(taxa_bold, bold_seq, marker = 'COI-5P') 
# Convert the list of sequences to a data frame
sequences_df <- do.call(rbind, sequences)




# Filter sequences based on the "COI-5P" marker. Despite the markes parameter, some files may have integrated multiple loci. The other sequences are removed from the R object
coi5p_sequences <- sequences_df %>% 
  filter(marker == "COI-5P")

# Write sequences to a file
write.fasta(
  sequences = as.list(coi5p_sequences$sequence), 
  names = as.list(coi5p_sequences$id), 
  nbchar = 60, 
  file.out = 'coi5p_Mollusca.fasta'
)
```